# Join with Laravel 4 using Eloquent

Tags: mysql, join, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following Models and related database tables.
Resource
Standard
Resource_Standard

I've given both the tables a belongsToMany correctly and all the naming conventions are correct.  I'm trying to do a join on a query, but I keep getting an error that the field I'm checking against doesn't exist.  Since I have several values to check against I'm passing them as an array to the query builder.  Here is how I'm building my query:

```
$resource = Resource::where(function($query) use($values)
{
    if($values["grade"] != 0)
        $query->where('grade_id', '=', $values["grade"]); 
    if($values['subject'] != 0)
        $query->where('subject_id', '=', $values['subject']);
    if($values['types'] != '')
    {
        if(is_array($values['types']) && count($values['types'])> 0)
            $query->whereIn('resourcetype_id', $values['types']);
        else
            $query->where('resourcetype_id', '=', $values['types']);
    }
    if($values['standards'] != '')
    {
        if(is_array($values['standards']) && count($values['standards'])> 0)
        {
            $query->join('resource_standard', 'resource_standard.resource_id', '=', 'resource.id')
                    ->with('standards')->whereIn('resource_standard.standard_id', $values['standards']);
        }
        else
        {
            $query->join('resource_standard', 'resource_standard.resource_id', '=', 'resource.id')
                    ->with('standards')->where('resource_standard.standard_id', '=', $values['standards']);
        }
    }
})->distinct()->take(30)->get();
```

When there is a standard_id to check against it gives the following error:

```
{
    "error":{
                "type":"Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
                "message":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'resource_standard.standard_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select distinct * from `resources` where (`grade_id` = 2 and `subject_id` = 1 and `resource_standard`.`standard_id` in (4832, 4833)) limit 30)",
                "file":"\/Users\/luke\/Dropbox\/DEV\/PHP\/4aplus\/4aplus\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Connection.php","line":555
            }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the relative code you are using to come up with the `$values` array?  Is it possible that `$values[foo]` could be `null` or `undefined`?

Comment: That's not possible, I took the join out and output the query it was generating and the values were there.  It's just not recognizing the join for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can `join` using `Eloquent` model as well. Just use following code:

```
$resource = Resource::join('resource_standard', 'resource_standard.resource_id', '=', 'resources.id')
```

Instead of this:

```
$resource = DB::table('resources')->join('resource_standard', 'resource_standard.resource_id', '=', 'resources.id')
```

Don't forget to call `->get()` at last.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using `DB::table` rather than the Model.  I guess you can't do a join with a model perhaps.

```
$resource = DB::table('resources')->join('resource_standard', 'resource_standard.resource_id', '=', 'resources.id')
```

Comment: You can do all the same on the Model query, the error said you had wrong column name there.

Comment: Right, because it didn't recognize the join.  It didn't see the joined table so it didn't recognize the column.

Comment: It's not that it didn't recognize - Model query is built on the same Query Builder you use with `DB::table`, so something else was wrong.